# VBA - Evaluate all Statements when more than 1 can be true

Tags: vba, excel, comparison

I want to evaluate a list of statements for a Cell (e.g. has top border, has bottom border etc.) and pass the findings to a collection object. However If/elseif will stop evaluating when it finds the first true statement, same holds for Select Case.

Is there any other way that I can use to do this?

```
Dim BorderColl As Collection
Set BorderColl = New Collection 

If RngCell.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle <> xlNone Then

  BorderColl.Add "xlDiagonalDown", LCase("xlDiagonalDown")

ElseIf RngCell.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle <> xlNone Then

  BorderColl.Add "xlDiagonalUp", LCase("xlDiagonalUp")

ElseIf RngCell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone Then

  BorderColl.Add "xlEdgeBottom", LCase("xlEdgeBottom")

ElseIf RngCell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle <> xlNone Then

  BorderColl.Add "xlEdgeLeft", LCase("xlEdgeLeft")

ElseIf RngCell.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle <> xlNone Then

  BorderColl.Add "xlEdgeRight", LCase("xlEdgeRight")

ElseIf RngCell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle <> xlNone Then

  BorderColl.Add "xlEdgeTop", LCase("xlEdgeTop")

End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change the elseif to if. You will have N if/endif blocks (where N is the number of properties you are evaluating). Then when one is successful it will just move on to the next one.

```
if someproperty then: do something
if someOtherProperty then: do something else
```

etc etc

Comment: Sometimes the answer is so obvious but the mind has stopped working... thanks a lot!

Comment: Although this is a perfectly good solution, i would reccomend against using ":" as it prevents you from placing a break point between the 2 parts, making it harder to debug.

Comment: Issun, Completely true, i just use it in these cases because the logic is so simple, looking at the collection at the end of it will tell you what went wrong (if anything).

Answer (score 6):

Cant you just use

```
Dim BorderColl As Collection
Set BorderColl = New Collection 

If RngCell.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
    BorderColl.Add "xlDiagonalDown", LCase("xlDiagonalDown")
End If
If RngCell.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
    BorderColl.Add "xlDiagonalUp", LCase("xlDiagonalUp")
End If
.
.
.
```

?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use a series of If-Then statements, one for each thing you want to check.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you?

```
Dim rngcell As Range, lBorder As Long, sStyles As Variant

    sStyles = Split(",,,,XLDIAGONALDOWN,XLDIAGONALUP,XLEDGELEFT,XLEDGETOP,XLEDGEBOTTOM,XLEDGERIGHT,XLINSIDEVERTICAL,XLINSIDEHORIZONTAL", ",")

    Set rngcell = Range("A1")
    For lBorder = 5 To 12
        If rngcell.Borders(lBorder).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
            Debug.Print lBorder, sStyles(lBorder - 1)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: thanks, that looks the prefered option if my list of statements was huge.